# Sql connetion doesn't open in windows service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, service, windows-services, sqlconnection

I have a simple windows service and within this service I'm trying to connect to a sql server in a timer block (I tried to do that only once in onStart method -> same result).

For the moment I'm trying just to execute a select, using the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection())
        {
                var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionString);
                string commanda = "SELECT Moneda, SimbolMoneda FROM NomMoneda WHERE                                    Moneda != '' AND SimbolMoneda != ''";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commanda, sqlConnection);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                IDataReader reader;
                sc.ConnectionString = _sqlConnectionString;
                sc.Open();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            }
```

I attached the service to debug, and I noticed that it didn't pass by this line of code `sc.Open()`.

The service is not on the same machine as the sql server, but I have tried to install it under different users, LocalSystem, NetworkService, user within the same domain with the sql server, but with no result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your connection string

Comment: is the connection string using sspi/trusted? or sql server auth? in the case of sspi/trusted: does the service's account have access to that sql server/database? also - see the sql server's event log: http://colinmackay.co.uk/2013/07/26/tip-of-the-day-how-to-tell-why-your-app-couldnt-log-on-to-sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple, but hard to detect. My connection string wasn't prefixed with the @ char:

```
   ex: _connectionString = @"Data Source =.......";
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you may have a logical error in this code. You are using `sc` for the `SqlConnection`, but when you create the command object you use `sqlConnection`, which is never actually opened.

This line is the problem:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commanda, sqlConnection);
```

Try the following instead:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commanda, sc);
```

**EDIT at 10:22 following user comment**

Just to confirm that you have made the change as indicated, I've re-jigged your code.  Could you try the following:

```
using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection())
{
    sc.ConnectionString = _sqlConnectionString;
    sc.Open();

    string commanda = "SELECT Moneda, SimbolMoneda FROM NomMoneda WHERE Moneda != '' AND SimbolMoneda != ''";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commanda, sc);
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    IDataReader reader;
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: I did the changes but with no luck. I'm using this code within lightswitch and wcf ria application where it works fine, but don't know where could be the problem, maybe is a security issue and the sql server doesn't allow the access, I have to do some more researches. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that whatever the issue is it would be easier to figure out if you had a logging mechanism in place to catch and log unhandled exceptions. Due to the fact that Windows Services do not have a user interface you should implement logging from the beginning. Otherwise you will get to a point where the service terminates unexpectedly and what little information you gather from the system logs won't be enough to help you.

In short, add file logging and you'll probably figure out the issue immediately.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, indeed, a file logging will be useful. It seems to be a problem with the connection, maybe I don't have the correct rights, I have to do some more researches. That code works fine from a wcf ria or lightswitch application, but from a windows service or console application doesn't open the connection.